# Antlr parsing numbers problem

Tags: antlr, grammar

I have a problem parsing integer & hex numbers. I want to parse C++ enums with the following rules:

```
grammar enum;

rule_enum
:   'enum' ID '{' enum_values+ '}'';';

enum_values
:   enum_value (COMMA enum_value)+;

enum_value
:   ID ('=' number)?;

number  :   hex_number | integer_number;

hex_number
:   '0' 'x' HEX_DIGIT+;

integer_number
:   DIGIT+;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
DIGIT   :   ('0'..'9');

COMMA   :   ',';


ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
```

The problem I have is the following - when parsing code like:

```
enum Enum
{
    Option1 = 0,
    Option2 = 1
};
```

it does not recognize the 0 as integer_number but tries to parse it as hex_number. How can I resolve this?

Thank you.
Tobias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, fragment rules can only be "seen" by lexer rules, not parser rules. So, the following is invalid:

```
integer_number
:   DIGIT+; // can't use DIGIT here!

fragment
DIGIT   :   ('0'..'9');
```

To fix your ambiguity with these numbers, it's IMO best to make these `integer`- and `hex` numbers lexer rules instead of parser rules.

An example:

```
grammar enum;

rule_enum
:   'enum' ID '{' enum_values+ '}'';';

enum_values
:   enum_value (COMMA enum_value)+;

enum_value
:   ID ('=' number)?;

number
  :  HEX_NUMBER
  |  INTEGER_NUMBER
  ;

HEX_NUMBER
:   '0' 'x' HEX_DIGIT+;

INTEGER_NUMBER
:   DIGIT+;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
DIGIT   :   ('0'..'9');

COMMA   :   ',';

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;

SPACE : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {skip();};
```

which produces the following parse tree of your example snippet:

[image]

Comment: thank you - I wasn't aware of the fine difference between lexer & parser rules.

Comment: This grammar does not handle negative numbers, as far as I can see

Answer (score 1):

The following ANTLR works for just the number bit of the enum. 
(editted to include Bart's advice below)

```
grammar enum;

number  :   
    integer_number | hex_number ;

hex_number
    :   HEX_NUMBER;

integer_number
    :   INT_NUMBER;


HEX_NUMBER
    :   HEX_INTRO HEX_DIGIT+;

INT_NUMBER
    :   DIGIT+;

HEX_INTRO
    :   '0x';


DIGIT   :   ('0'..'9');


HEX_DIGIT 
    : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;
```

Comment: `HEX_INTRO (DIGIT | HEX_DIGIT)` will only match a single hex digits (it fails to match `0xFF`). Also, the `DIGIT` part can be omitted since `HEX_DIGIT` already contains these. But, I highly discourage to put these things inside parser rules: I am pretty sure C++ parser themselves also handle the tokenizing of integer, hex and octal numbers on a lexer level.

Comment: The above grammar matches 0xFF (when the active rule is number:) on my copy of Antlr (1.4.2). Would your advice to be to match Hex numbers in the entirety at the Lexer level?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I missed the `+` after `HEX_DIGIT`. I must say it's a bit misleading: calling something `HEX_DIGIT` and making it match more than one digit! :)

Comment: Jimmy, your latest suggestion now causes the lexer to possibly produce a token that consists of `'0x'` only. Better make `HEX_INTRO` a fragment, or just stick '0x'` inside `HEX_NUMBER` (in which case, you simply copied my answer! :))

Comment: The same goes for `HEX_DIGIT`: if an `F` is all alone in the source to be parsed, it gets tokenized as a `HEX_DIGIT`: that can't be the intention. Better make that a fragment as well.

Comment: Thanks Bart, I think I learned a little more about Antlr in the last 1/2 hour - so I'll up your answer - you can down my answer if you like for blatant plagarism :-)

Comment: Nah, that won't be necessary! :)

Comment: This grammar does not handle negative numbers, as far as I can see